# Is it possible to enter letters in iPhone native calculator app?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

I found this wholesome meme image online that shows the native iPhone calculator app displaying the text `ur cute`.

[image]

When I saw this, I didn't think you could type or display actual letters or words in the calculator app, so I tried playing around with it on my phone. I used both the simplified and the scientific calculator.

I could not get any letters to appear. I also tried copy from the Notes app to the calculator app but I could only copy the text from the calculator, not paste (*Note: I did this on my iPhone SE IOS v13.3.1*).

**Is it possible to enter words/letters into the native iPhone calculator application somehow?**

Or was this a feature that was available at some point and removed or is this a  bug?

Or is it not possible and this image just photo-shopped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot enter letters into the calculator on the iPhone.  The image was most likely photo-shopped.  You can copy what appears in the calculator window but you can only paste digits back into display.